# Inconsistent State Comparison Java

Tags: java, multithreading, volatile, mutable

In ***Java Concurrency In Practice*** an example* is given to demonstrate the issue of *visibility*, where two different threads may not see the up-to-date state of any particular mutable object because of a lack of synchronisation.

```
public class Holder {
    private int n;
    public Holder(int n) { this.n = n; }

    public void assertSanity() {
        if (n != n){
            throw new AssertionError("This statement is false.");
        }
    }
```

In this particular example, the book states that should a Thread "A" first initialise and publish it via a Thread unsafe manner, like:

```
public Holder holder;
public void initialize() {
    holder = new Holder(42);
}
```

And then a Thread "B" calls `holder.assertSanity()`, that it is entirely possible that the `AssertionError` will be thrown, due to an inconsistent state.

Now, I understand the basic premise of the argument, where a change made to a mutable variable may never be observed by another thread. But what I am confused here is the fact that it is comparing the same (or so I think) reference `n != n`.

Doesn't this compare the value of the mutable primitive field `private int n`? Regardless of the fact that `n` may now be of value 42 to Thread A, and of value 0 (default) to Thread B, shouldn't a direct call to check it's value in the **same** thread be *consistent*? i.e. Calling `assertSanity()` in Thread A would check if `42 != 42`, and in Thread B, `0 != 0`?

*Referenced from 3.5 Safe Publication, Listings 3.14 & 3.15 in the book.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is that in the expression `n != n` the variable `n` will be loaded twice (assuming no optimization of the bytecode). Between these two loads, another thread could change the value.

Answer (score 1):

During comparing in thread B `n != n`, B retrieve `n` two times. Meanwhile the constructor runs in thread A would modify the value of n, from default 0, to 42.

Comment: ?? How does B get a reference to an object not yet constructed?

Comment: @BasilBourque the book refer to it as "partially constructed objects".